# How does Kafka specify key alias for Client Authentication?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, keystore, client-certificates

I've seen many places that show enabling Kafka client authentication using the same example code as here:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/latest/topics/kafka_security.html#deploying_ssl_for_kafka__d18295e284

Namely:

```
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
```

My question is, how does the client specify the particular key within the keystore to use? Everywhere else I see JKS keystores discussed, keys are specified using an alias. The only things I can figure is that:

- The alias is expected to be hard-coded (I can find no reference to this fact, however)
- It is expected that only one key is in the keystore, and thus it uses the first key it finds
- It scans and uses the first where the password matches the value of the ssl.key.password property

Answer (score 6):

None of the above. If you don't specify `ssl.keymanager.algorithm` (see [SslConfigs:96](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/7a7d4cb5819b169db2f40f0ca2efc04043ff10df/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/config/SslConfigs.java#L96)) then it uses the JVM default (see [SslEngineBuilder:138](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/7a7d4cb5819b169db2f40f0ca2efc04043ff10df/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/security/ssl/SslEngineBuilder.java#L138)), which is probably going to be `SunX509` (the only standard name is `PKIX`, but there's no indication of what that does differently; see [Standard Algorithm Names § KeyManagerFactory algorithms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyManagerFactory)). Despite the description of the standard algorithm, [RFC 3280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3280/) does not specify a key selection process per se. However, the actual implemention simply selects *some* key of one of the desired types for which the corresponding certificate's certification path contains one of the desired issuers (see call chain starting at [SunX509KeyManagerImpl.chooseClientAlias](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/blob/aa318070b27849f1fe00d14684b2a40f7b29bf79/jdk/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java#L204)).

So the client's choice of key alias is going to be dictated by the certificate issuers that the server says it trusts and the types of keys that the server says it accepts (this is almost always RSA today, but may be different in the future or in specific scenarios). If you have just 1 RSA key issued by a CA that the server trusts, then that's the key it will pick. If 0, then the connection will fail, and if 2 or more, you don't know which one will be picked. In particular, having an expired and unexpired cert that both match the criteria is a recipe for trouble.

I found some interesting details on `KeyManager`s and `KeyStore`s on a [terse systems blog post](https://tersesystems.com/blog/2018/09/08/keymanagers-and-keystores/), but some of the customization they talk about won't be possible without patching Kafka itself. If you need to control key selection with more precision, you'll probably have to implement your own KeyManager or use a third-party one that meets your needs.